# How to execute where clause in T-SQL select statement based on conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Below is my stored procedure in T-SQL. I have two parameters `@id` and `@questionId`. Select statement uses both parameters for selection.

What I am looking for is ways to not use condition if parameter has value as 0. In detail, if @id has 0 as value, filter where `pa.Id = @id` should not execute and when `@questionId =0`, and `pa.QuestionId = @questionId` should not execute.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[spOptions] 
    (@id INT, @questionId INT)
AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT * 
    FROM PossibleAnswers pa
    INNER JOIN vFormAnswers fa ON pa.QuestionId = fa.QuestionId
    WHERE pa.Id = @id 
      AND pa.QuestionId = @questionId
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this. Here if parameter is passed as 0 then it will execute or condition 0=0 which is true and consider all of the records.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[spOptions] 
(  @id int=0, @questionId int=0  )  ---- here pass default value as 0 so this is optional to pass from front end
AS
BEGIN   
select * from PossibleAnswers pa
inner join  vFormAnswers fa
on pa.QuestionId = fa.QuestionId
where (pa.Id = @id or @id = 0)    ---- here if @id = 0 then condition will be 0=0 
and (pa.QuestionId = @questionId or @questionId=0)
END
GO
```

Comment: This may the the shortest way to get to your desired result, but this may introduce a not optimal query execution plan. Personally, I'd either build up a dynamic statement or create a few if/then paths for the correct filter. For more detailed information, see this great post by Kimberly Tripp https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/